# MySQL query returning weird error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I am trying to insert some data into a database with my own mysql class (built on top of pdo) but I keed getting some weird errors

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid
> datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Google Chrome' for
> column 'user_id' at row 1 in
> C:\wamp64\www\LVWeb\Core\Database\database.mysql-pdo.php on line 44
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366
> Incorrect integer value: 'Google Chrome' for column 'user_id' at row 1
> in C:\wamp64\www\LVWeb\Core\Database\database.mysql-pdo.php on line 44

Table structure: http://prntscr.com/c3pgzi

My Query function:

```
public function Query($query, $vars = []){
        $Statement = $this -> con -> prepare($query);

        if(is_array($vars))
            foreach($vars AS $key => $val){
                if(is_string($val))
                    $Statement->bindParam($key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                else if(is_integer($val))
                    $Statement->bindParam($key, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }

        return $Statement->execute();
    }
```

The part where I try to insert the data:

```
$a = "INSERT INTO sessions (ses_id, user_id, ip, os, browser) VALUES
    (:ses_id, :user_id, :ip, :os, :browser)";

$this->DB->Query($a, [
    ':ses_id'   =>  $session,
    ':user_id'  =>  $response['ID'],
    ':ip'       =>  GetIp(),
    ':os'       =>  GetOS(),
    ':browser'  =>  GetBrowser()['name']
]);
```

So I have tested every variable out to see if they are the right type:

1. $session = string
2. $response['ID'] = integer
3. GetIp() = string
4. GetOs() = string
5. GetBrowser()['name'] = string

Comment: 'Google Chrome'  is a string. not an interger

Comment: Weird errors? They can't be clearer.. it even tells you. You tried to supply `Google Chrome` for an integer. You made a classic mistake trying to make PDO "better" by creating some silly code that just makes it worse. Dump your function, use prepared statements directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a funny issue - the cause is that the parameters are bound as references in `PDOStatement->bindParam()`.

I.e. in the `foreach` loop you say the following: "let :ses_id be bound to whatever is in $val now", then on the next iteration - "let :user_id be bound to whatever is in $val now", etc. At the the end of the loop all parameters are effectively bound to the same thing - variable `$val`. And what does that value contain? The last thing that PHP assigned to it - `$vars[':browser']`.

Thus `$Statement->execute()` tries to insert a record with all the fields equal to the name of the browser.

You need to change the code of `foreach` to the following:

`foreach($vars AS $key => $val){
    if (is_string($val))
        $Statement->bindParam($key, $vars[$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    else if(is_integer($val))
        $Statement->bindParam($key, $vars[$key], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}`

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback!
It worked, I'm marking this as the solution